# Javascript and esri.dijit.PopupMobile

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I currently have a wonderful mobile version of our site up in which it uses PopupMobile to display the requested info. I also map a button on the map that allows the user to do a random function.

The problem that I am running in to is since the button is on top of the map, when a user expands the mobile popup the button is on top of it as well. Is there a way to keep the button on top of the map, but make it go underneath or not be there when the popup is expanded?

I have included a small picture illustrating my issue. The left side is when there is just a map there, and the right is when a user expanded the popup infowindow.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control whether or not the button shows on top of the popup or under it by using z-index. A z-index of 10 for your node that becomes the dijit button should put it under your mobile popup. Here's an example with a plain html button:  http://jsfiddle.net/eQtcp/